# Forever looping over channel messages across several goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, mqtt, channel

I would like to write a relay app that listens to a MQTT server, transforms the payload, and relays it to Google Cloud IoT Core.

For now, I have a working solution on my dev laptop (it doesn't transform the data yet). Basically, what it is intended to do is:

- Create a `messages` channel
- Create a `jwtToken` channel
- Launch a jwtToken generation goroutine that updates the JWT
- Launch a relay goroutine that connects to GCP IoTCore and publishes the messages it receives on the `messages` channel
- Launch the listen goroutine to connect to the MQTT server and record what it gets onto the `messages` channel

The app is intended to run forever on a K8S pod.

```golang
package main

import (
    // ...
)

func main() {
    exit := make(chan string)
    messages := make(chan mqtt.Message)
    jwtTokens := make(chan string)

    mqttServerUri := os.Getenv("MQTT_FULL_URI")
    uri, err := url.Parse(mqttServerUri)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    topic := uri.Path[1:len(uri.Path)]
    if topic == "" {
        topic = "test"
    }

    go jwtTokenService(jwtTokens)
    go relay(messages, jwtTokens)
    go listen(uri, "#", messages)

    for {
        select {
        case <-exit:
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }
}

// connect Connects to the local MQTT Broker
func connect(clientId string, uri *url.URL) mqtt.Client {
    opts := createClientOptions(clientId, uri)
    client := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
    token := client.Connect()
    for !token.WaitTimeout(3 * time.Second) {
    }
    if err := token.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return client
}

func createClientOptions(clientId string, uri *url.URL) *mqtt.ClientOptions {
    opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions()
    opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("tcp://%s", uri.Host))
    opts.SetUsername(uri.User.Username())
    password, _ := uri.User.Password()
    opts.SetPassword(password)
    opts.SetClientID(clientId)
    return opts
}

// googleConnect Connects to Google IoT Core MQTT Broker
func googleConnect(clientId string, uri *url.URL, jwtToken string) mqtt.Client {
    opts := createGoogleClientOptions(clientId, uri, jwtToken)
    client := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
    token := client.Connect()
    for !token.WaitTimeout(3 * time.Second) {
    }
    if err := token.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return client
}

func createGoogleClientOptions(clientId string, uri *url.URL, jwtToken string) *mqtt.ClientOptions {
    opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions()
    opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("ssl://%s", uri.Host))
    opts.SetUsername("unused")
    opts.SetProtocolVersion(4)
    opts.SetPassword(jwtToken)
    opts.SetClientID(clientId)
    certpool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pemCerts, err := ioutil.ReadFile("roots.pem")
    if err == nil {
        certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pemCerts)
    }
    config := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            certpool,
        ClientAuth:         tls.NoClientCert,
        ClientCAs:          nil,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{},
        MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,
    }
    opts.SetTLSConfig(config)
    return opts
}

// listen Listens to the local MQTT Broker and adds the payloads to the messages channel
func listen(uri *url.URL, topic string, messages chan mqtt.Message) {
    client := connect("sub", uri)
    client.Subscribe(topic, 2, func(client mqtt.Client, msg mqtt.Message) {
        log.Println("Receiving ", string(msg.Payload()), " on topic: ", msg.Topic())
        messages <- msg
    })
}

// createJWT creates a Cloud IoT Core JWT for the given project id.
// algorithm can be one of ["RS256", "ES256"].
func createJWT(projectID string, privateKeyPath string, algorithm string, expiration time.Duration) (string, error) {
    claims := jwt.StandardClaims{
        Audience:  projectID,
        IssuedAt:  time.Now().Unix(),
        ExpiresAt: time.Now().Add(expiration).Unix(),
    }
    keyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(privateKeyPath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.GetSigningMethod(algorithm), claims)

    switch algorithm {
    case "RS256":
        privKey, _ := jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM(keyBytes)
        return token.SignedString(privKey)
    case "ES256":
        privKey, _ := jwt.ParseECPrivateKeyFromPEM(keyBytes)
        return token.SignedString(privKey)
    }

    return "", errors.New("Cannot find JWT algorithm. Specify 'ES256' or 'RS256'")
}

// jwtTokenService Maintains the lifecycle of JWTs
func jwtTokenService(jwtTokens chan string) {
    projectId := "domalys-202111"
    privateKeyPath := filepath.Join("keyfiles", "rsa_private.pem")

    log.Println("Generating initial JWT token")
    generateJwtToken(projectId, privateKeyPath, jwtTokens)

    timer := time.NewTicker(40 * time.Minute)
    for range timer.C {
        log.Println("Generating new JWT token")
        generateJwtToken(projectId, privateKeyPath, jwtTokens)
    }
}

// generateJwtToken generates a new JWT
func generateJwtToken(projectId string, privateKeyPath string, jwtTokens chan string) {
    jwtToken, err := createJWT(projectId, privateKeyPath, "RS256", 120)
    if err == nil {
        jwtTokens <- jwtToken
        log.Println("New JWT token generated")
    }
}

// relay Relays the messages handled by listen to Google IoT Core
// Connection is refreshed whenever the JWT is refreshed
func relay(messages chan mqtt.Message, jwtTokens chan string) {
    googleUri, err := url.Parse("mqtt://mqtt.googleapis.com:443/")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    clientIdSlice := []string{"projects", "domalys-202111", "locations", "europe-west1", "registries", "domalys-mqtt", "devices", "mqtt-relay"}
    clientId := strings.Join(clientIdSlice, "/")

    for token := range jwtTokens {
        log.Println("Connecting with fresh token")
        client := googleConnect(clientId, googleUri, token)
        for {
            msg := <-messages
            payload := string(msg.Payload())
            topic := "/devices/mqtt-relay/events/" + msg.Topic()
            log.Println("Sending : ", payload)
            client.Publish(topic, 1, false, payload)
        }
    }
}
```

Everything runs perfectly locally. However, whenever I send push it to my K8S stack, itsimply stops after the first payload is received and relayed.

I tried using a buffered channel in `main()` like this :

```golang
messages := make(chan mqtt.Message, 10)
```

...but it just plays the scheme 10 times and stops. I am intrigued : why does this work locally forever, but not in production?

Comment: Get a stack trace when the program is hanging, and it will help you see where your goroutines are blocked. I don't understand how the `relay` could work, since you never break from the inner loop. This appears to be a few serial operations with no need for the extra channels and goruotines.

Comment: I'm with @JimB on this: the `relay` appears to drain `messages` only when a new JWT token is sent (from elsewhere). I have too little knowledge about the setup to try to tell whether that's correct or not. To get the stack trace, make sure the process' stderr is redirected somewhere and send the process the `SIGQUIT` signal. You might also use the facilities of the [net/http/pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) and grab the dump of all running goroutines by doing GET to `/goroutines?debug=1` on the endpoint served by that package.

Comment: Think about network errors (eg. url.Parse("mqtt://mqtt.googleapis.com:443/")) your local network can call these apis, but how about your K8s network